# How can I get the count of https response code from a log file?

Tags: unix

I have a set of log files of load balancer and I want to get the list with total number of count  `https` code wise. To do the same I'm using below set of commands but I'm not getting a proper output. Can someone please help me with that and let me know what is the issue?

```bash
    cat `ls -rt SampleFile.log||tail -1|head -1` \
    |awk '{print $4,$7,$8,$9,$10}' \
    |cut -c2- \
    |awk '{print $1" "$3}' FS='"' \
    |awk '{print $1,$2":"$3,$4}' FS=":" OFS=" " \
    |awk '{print $1,$2,$4}' \
    |sed 's/\/Jan\// 01 /;s/\/Feb\// 02 /;s/\/Mar\// 03 /;s/\/Apr\// 04 /;s/\/May\// 05 /;s/\/Jun\// 06 /;s/\/Jul\// 07 /;s/\/Aug\// 08 /;s/\/Sep\// 09 /;s/\/Oct\// 10 /;s/\/Nov\// 11 /;s/\/Dec\// 12 /' \
    |awk '{print $3,$2,$1,$4,$5}' \
    |sort \
    |uniq -c \
    |awk 'BEGIN { FS=" " }{print $4"."$3"."$2" "$5","$6","$1}' \
    |gawk 'BEGIN{FS=","} {LN[$1]; HD[$2]; MX[$1,$2]=$3} END { printf "%s", "\n \n Timestamp      "; for (i in HD) printf " |  %s ", i; print ""; for (j in LN) { printf "%s",j; for (i in HD) { if (MX[j,i] =="") { printf " | %5d",0 } else { printf " | %5d", MX[j,i] } } print "" } }' \
    |sort
```

SampleFile.log

> 10.99.2.216 - - [06/Sep/2021:19:00:00 +0200] "GET /****/customer/subscriptions/*****/accounts;filter=all;scope=node
> HTTP/1.1" 200 1136 dCvQi12Mt20000000 server:36093
> 10.99.2.216 - - [06/Sep/2021:19:00:00 +0200] "PUT /api/email/tokens/d11111d2-278a-4fed-ae57-9f50bf277025/emails
> HTTP/1.1" 200 78 gY4NZ1BMv20000000 server:36090
> 10.99.2.216 - - [06/Sep/2021:19:00:00 +0200] "GET /domain/inlife/brands/77/subscriptions/mobile/possibleproducts
> HTTP/1.1" 200 10877 dCvQi13Mt20000000 server.com:36091

Expected Output(Sample): (It should give the output as total number of https response wise count.)
[image]

The same command is working without any issue, if I'm using with below set of log files.
SampleLog_2.log:

> 10.99.2.216 - - [27/Jun/2021:16:00:00 +0200]  [105000] "GET /contractextension/subscriptions/contractextensioneligibility HTTP/1.1" 200 943 03eEr11g400000000 server.de.pri.o2.com:10582
> 10.99.2.216 - - [27/Jun/2021:16:00:00 +0200]  [280000] "GET /invoice/xstack/accounts/invoiceoverview HTTP/1.1" 200 18589 uCWE718c400000000 server.de.pri.o2.com:36094
> 10.99.2.216 - - [27/Jun/2021:16:00:00 +0200]  [408000] "GET /invoice/xstack/accounts/invoice/documents HTTP/1.1" 200 5962 GrDqn1Jf400000000 server.de.pri.o2.com:36094

What is the difference with both the sample_files and what command I need to change to get the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very easy to cut another set of block from your log file. Use below command and it will do the needful what your have requested.

```
cat `ls -rt access-duration.log||tail -1|head -1`|awk '{print 
$4,$6,$7,$8,$9}'|cut -c2-|awk '{print $1" "$3}' FS='"'|awk '{print 
$1,$2":"$3,$4}' FS=":" OFS=" "|awk '{print $1,$2,$4}'|sed 's/\/Jan\// 
01 /;s/\/Feb\// 02 /;s/\/Mar\// 03 /;s/\/Apr\// 04 /;s/\/May\// 05 
/;s/\/Jun\// 06 /;s/\/Jul\// 07 /;s/\/Aug\// 08 /;s/\/Sep\// 09 
/;s/\/Oct\// 10 /;s/\/Nov\// 11 /;s/\/Dec\// 12 /'|awk '{print 
$3,$2,$1,$4,$5}'|sort|uniq -c|awk 'BEGIN { FS=" " }{print $4"."$3"."$2" 
"$5","$6","$1}'|gawk 'BEGIN{FS=","} {LN[$1]; HD[$2]; MX[$1,$2]=$3} END 
{ printf "%s","\n \n  Timestamp      "; for (i in HD) printf "|     
%s", i; print ""; for (j in LN) {printf "%s",j; for (i in HD) { if 
(MX[j,i] =="") { printf " | %5d",0 } else { printf " | %5d", MX[j,i] } 
} print "" } }' |sort
```

I made the changes only in below line  and replaced with -1 after $4
'{print $4,**$6,$7,$8,$9**} and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the difference with both the sample_files

The difference is the additional bracketed column in *SampleLog_2.log* after the timestamp.

> and what command I need to change to get the expected output.

In order to be less dependent on unneeded columns, you can for example replace the pipeline

```
cat `ls -rt SampleFile.log||tail -1|head -1` \
|awk '{print $4,$7,$8,$9,$10}' \
|cut -c2- \
|awk '{print $1" "$3}' FS='"' \
|awk '{print $1,$2":"$3,$4}' FS=":" OFS=" " \
|awk '{print $1,$2,$4}'
```

with

```
sed 's?.*\(../.../....\):\(..:..\):.. .*" \(...\).*?\1 \2 \3?' SampleFile.log
```

There's probably room for further simplifications in the following stages.

Comment: It doesn't work as expected